# How to print a BST alphabetically?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a BST that is in-order traversal so it prints from min to max but I also have to print it in alphabetical order, I don't know how, I tried in-order traversal but it didn't work.

```
//Method to insert values to BST
    ABBNodo insertar(ABBNodo raiz, int data, String nombre, double salario){
        if(raiz==null){
            raiz=new ABBNodo(data, nombre, salario);
            raiz.setData(data);
            raiz.setNombre(nombre);
            raiz.setIzq(null); raiz.setDer(null);   
            }else{
                if(data<raiz.getData()) raiz.setIzq(insertar(raiz.getIzq(),data, nombre, salario));
                else if(data>raiz.getData()) raiz.setDer(insertar(raiz.getDer(),data, nombre, salario));
        }
        return raiz;
    }

//Recursive method for in-order traversal
        void inOrden(ABBNodo raiz){
            if(raiz!=null){
                inOrden(raiz.getIzq());
                System.out.println(raiz.getData()+" "+raiz.getNombre());
                inOrden(raiz.getDer());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create another BST ordered alphabetically. Or put all the nodes into an array/list then sort it.

Comment: If your BST is ordered by `data`, the names are pretty much going to be in a random order through the tree.  So there's no tree traversal that will give you the names in order.  You'll need to collect all the names and then call a `sort` method.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your posted code that addresses alphabetical order; it works only with the existing data fields.

- Copy this code to the bottom of the same file.
- You will use this copy to create an alpha BST.

  - change the names of the routines.
  - change the insertion routine to key on `nombre` instead of `data`
- Traverse the original tree.  As you encounter each node, insert that node into the new (alpha) tree.

You now have two trees: one sorted by data, one by alphabet.

If you need to have only one set of nodes, then you'll need to update your node structure to have a second set of pointers for alphabetical order.

Comment: How can I focus the insertion routine in `nombre`?

Comment: That's is pretty much asking me to write your homework for you.  You use `nombre` as the key instead of `data`.  You already wrote the code for `data`, so this should be a simple substitution.

Comment: Yes, but I can't compare to set the node right or left because `nombre` is String.

Comment: Read your class materials or documentation on string comparisons.